# how to highlight some images using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to highlight some of the images and blur rest of the images onclick event using jquery.

```
<div class="portfolio-item2"  data-id="id-0" data-type="cat-item-4" style="float: left" id="abc">   
    <div>
        <span class="image-block">
            <a class="image-zoom" href="images/big/p1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" title="Wall-E">
                <img src= "images/thumbs/p1.jpg" alt="Wall-E" width="320" height="250" title="Wall-E" id="im"/>                    
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>  
</div>
<div class="portfolio-item2" data-id="id-1" data-type="cat-item-2" style="float: left"  id="abcs" > 
    <div>
        <span class="image-block">
            <a class="image-zoom" href="images/big/pic2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" title="Up">
                <img src="images/thumbs/p2.jpg" width="200" height="100" alt="Up" title="Up" />                    
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>  
</div>
```

this is my sample code. Please help

Comment: Can you rewrite your question above your source code? It is not clear what did you ask for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to the image that you what to blur

```
.bluredImages {
//reduce the opacity;    
}
```

or viceversa.

In jQuery, just add this class using **`.addClass('bluredImages ')`**

Updates:

For a cross-browser way to blur images using only CSS, check [**this**](http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/mkgyl)

Comment: Is there a cross-browser way to blur images using only CSS? If yes, which?

Comment: @til_b cross-browser?  IE usually breaks.  [Here](http://demosthenes.info/blog/534/Crossbrowser-Image-Blur-with-CSS) is an good demonstration of it

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.portfolio-item2.opaque {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

and

```
jQuery(function () {
    var $items = $('.portfolio-item2').click(function (e) {
        $items.not(this).addClass('opaque');
        $(this).removeClass('opaque');
        e.preventDefault();
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JM63q/)